# Есть ли в стандартной библиотеке c++ или в boost спинлок?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Есть ли в стандартной библиотеке c++ или в boost спинлок?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это std::atomic_flag

Пример:

```
std::atomic_flag lock = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
while (lock.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)); //заблочили


lock.clear(std::memory_order_release);                //разблочили
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag